# Help needed in computing Inter-rater, intra-rater variability

Tags: repeated-measures, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation, variability

I have been working on a test in which I need to quantify the variability in a process. The process in question involves positioning a number of landmarks on an anatomy. There are two sets of landmarks, one set forms a frame of reference around the bone while the other approximates the native orientation of the anatomy. The end result is a measurement of the orientation of the native anatomy of the patient.

My initial approach is to design this test around a Gage R&R (using Minitab) where 3 operators would each position the set of landmarks on the anatomy of 10 different patients and record the resulting measure of orientation. The whole process is repeated 3 times. In summary: 3 operators perform 3 trial measurements on 10 parts. (Is this called stratified sampling?)

The concern that I have is that I am not sure that the test really applies since the native orientation of the diseased anatomy of each patient is really independent between patients in contrast with a normal application of the Gage R&R where the parts are normally to have the same size.

Now for my first question: How would you recommend that I treat the information that I have collected to characterize the intra-operator and inter-operator variability? I have noticed that many papers treat this situation with an Intraclass Correlation Coefficient (ICC) however the details of this analysis go well beyond my skills. I would feel more confident defending an ANOVA or simple CI on the variance. Any thoughts or comments on this first question would be greatly appreciated.

My second question pertains to the computation of a CI on the variance: Can I combine the variance (s^2) computed for each anatomy (n=9) together for a total variance (n=90) even if they don’t share a common mean orientation?